# Can SET in MySQL be used by itself?

Tags: php, mysql

I am updating some old code and couldn't find anything on this.  Can `SET` be used by itself without UPDATE?  I think it was an error on the last programmer, but don't want to throw it out if it isn't.

The only way I have seen it used:

UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;

Here is their statement with $time being based on a timezone formula:

```
SET time_zone = '$time'
```

Here is more of the complete code:

```
$timezone = $_SESSION['time'];

if ($timezone < 10 && $timezone > -10) {
    if ($timezone < 0) {
        $timezone = substr($timezone, 1);
        $offset = "-0$timezone:00";
    } else {
        $offset = "+0$timezone:00";
    }
} else {
    if ($timezone < 0) {
        $timezone = substr($timezone, 1);
        $offset = "-$timezone:00";
    } else {
        $offset = "+$timezone:00";
    }
}
$qry= "SET time_zone = '$offset ' "; 
mysql_query($qry)
```

Comment: Yes, that sets a variable.  It has nothing to do with `UPDATE`.

Comment: [14.7.4 SET Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-statement.html)

Comment: This must be the PHP side of it

Comment: What's weird is that they $qry= "SET time_zone = '$time' ";     mysql_query($qry);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a per connection time zone setting.

From the manual page [MySQL Server Time Zone Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html)

> Per-connection time zones. Each client that connects has its own time
>   zone setting, given by the session `time_zone` variable. Initially, the
>   session variable takes its value from the `global time_zone` variable,
>   but the client can change its own time zone with this statement:
>
> mysql> SET time_zone = timezone;

Comment: If I get more than 2 upvotes for this, I go to meta to complain :p

Comment: Then we can use it like a normal statement in PDO, even though it is a global?

Comment: sure, like, `select now();` ... it makes a connection-level change that persists